# Flutter Firebase - How to open the app when tapping on email verification link send by Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, deep-linking

I am able to send an email verification link through Firebase on my flutter app. But I want to modify the link so that when the user taps on it, it will take them to an app screen defined by me. So basically deep linking. I looked around and found resources for deep linking but they all dealt with custom urls with things like newsletters in mind.

But I am looking to modify the verification email that Firebase sends in a deep link that opens a particular screen in the app.

Comment: You don't want to use deep linking there you can go to a verification class which check if the user email is verified or not so when you click on tht link the user will get verified and verification class will route you to the homescreen

Comment: Hi, thanks but can you point me to some resources for how can I implement this. Google is failing me here. Also not sure if this will open the app when clicking on the verification link

Comment: ok I will add some code in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

> After User register account you need to route to a new class where in
> the init function you will send a `sendEmailVerification();`

*See the below code*

```
user = auth.currentUser!; 
user.sendEmailVerification();
```

> In the initState() make a timer also which will check is the email is verified periodiclly.

so, say after every five seconds call this function so, it will be checking the email is verified or not.

*Refer the below function*

```
Future<void> checkEmailVerified() async {
    user = auth.currentUser!;
    await user.reload();
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      timer.cancel();
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
    }
  }
```

> If the user email gets verified pass the user to the Home screen

and also dispose the timer

*Refer the full code given below*

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:service_provider/constant/constant.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class VerifyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerifyScreenState createState() => _VerifyScreenState();
}

class _VerifyScreenState extends State<VerifyScreen> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late User user;
  late Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    user = auth.currentUser!;
    user.sendEmailVerification();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      checkEmailVerified();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/gif.gif',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain, height: 18.h),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'An email has been sent to ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.spartan(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    // textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: '"${user.email}"',
                      style: GoogleFonts.spartan(
                        color: Color(Const.primary),
                        // textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const TextSpan(text: ' please verify'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> checkEmailVerified() async {
    user = auth.currentUser!;
    await user.reload();
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      timer.cancel();
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**

Some user can skip this process by just closing the app from here. so, what you can do is when the user again loginin check if the user is verifed if the user's email is not verified again come to the verification page

*Thank you*

Comment: Sorry, this is exactly what I am doing and this is exactly what I don't want to do. 
I definitely need deep linking for this.

As I said in my question I want the verification link to "Open" the app and route to the relevant screen so that user don't have to go to the app manually. I don't want the verification link to open in a browser.

Hope I am making myself clearer.

Answer (score 0):

After sending verification link you have to use Firebase deep linking plugin and in Firebase console you create your own dynamic links and you should change your verification mail domain as dynamic links domain. You can this from authentication section template in Firebase console.

In first screen of your flutter screen make stateful and in initstate call function initDynamicLinks().

Dynamic link in firebase: https://customlink.page.link/auth

```
Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) async {
      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLinkData?.link;
      print("deepLink $deepLink");
      if (deepLink.path == "/auth") {
        print(deepLink);
        Get.toNamed(Routes.LOGIN_EMAIL_SCREEN);
      }
    }).onError((error) {
      print('onLink error');
      print(error.message);
    });
  }
```