# Forgot password inside app, instead of in web form

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Im using firebase auth for my flutter app, and I want to implement forgot password inside of the app, and not in web form. Is that possible? Currently the email just opens a form where user can enter their password.

I've tried searching everywhere for possible solutions, and nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/confirmPasswordReset.html?

Comment: Okay, but this still requires a code. Is there a way to open the app via email firebase sends, and send the code with it?

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+open+my+app+when+the+user+clicks+a+link+in+an+email? If so, this looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376461/flutter-firebase-how-to-open-the-app-when-tapping-on-email-verification-link-s